# How to add conditional redirect to each view in Pyramid?

Tags: python, redirect, request, conditional-statements, pyramid

I'd like to check a condition before each request and call different views.
How is that achieved?

One solution I can think of is adding something to subscriber NewRequest, but I am stuck:

```
@subscriber(NewRequest)
def new_request_subscriber(event):
  if condition:
    #what now?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@subscriber(NewRequest)
def new_request_subscriber(event):
  if condition:
    raise pyramid.httpexceptions.HTTPFound(location=somelocation) ## to issue a proper redirect
```

More info can be found here:
  http://pyramid.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/httpexceptions.html#pyramid.httpexceptions.HTTPFound

Comment: This should be a `raise`, you can't return anything from subscribers.

Answer (score 1):

Well you've given very little information about the "condition" or what you mean by "call different views", so I'll assume you do not want to invoke a redirect but instead you want the application to think a different URL is being requested. To do that you can look at `pyramid_rewrite`, which is pretty handy for these things, or you can just change the request's path within the `NewRequest` subscriber, since it is invoked before Pyramid dispatches to a view.

```
if request.path == '/foo':
    request.path = '/bar':

config.add_route('foo', '/foo') # never matches
config.add_route('bar', '/bar')
```

Comment: suppose i'd like to show always (for any url) sign_in page if user is sign_out

request.path is not modifible bacuase i got:
*** AttributeError: can't set attribute

Comment: sorry it's `request.path_info`, updated answer. You can show a page this way, but in that case you probably want to redirect using the `raise HTTPFound` method that @raj showed, or use Pyramid's auth system to handle it automatically.

Comment: I think that @Raj solution is the best for my case. Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another option to "check a condition ... and call different views" is to use custom view predicates

From [Cris McDonough's blog post](http://www.plope.com/weird_pyramid_urldispatch):

```
   def example_dot_com_host(info, request):
       if request.host == 'www.example.com:
           return True
```

That's a custom predicate there. It returns True if the hostname is www.example.com. Here's how we use it:

```
  @view_config(route_name='blogentry', request_method='GET')
  def get_blogentry(request):
      ...

  @view_config(route_name='blogentry', request_method='POST')
  def post_blogentry(request):
      ...

  @view_config(route_name='blogentry', request_method='GET', 
               custom_predicates=(example_dot_com_host,))
  def get_blogentry_example_com(request):
      ...

  @view_config(route_name='blogentry', request_method='POST', 
               custom_predicates=(example_dot_com_host,))
  def post_blogentry_example_com(request):
      ...
```

However, for your particular problem (display a sign in page if user has no permission to view the page) a better way to achieve this would be to [set up permissions](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/security.html#protecting-views-with-permissions) for views so the framework raises an exception when user has no permission, and then register a [custom view for that exception](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/views.html?awesome#custom-exception-views) which will show a sign in form.

Comment: Cool stuff i didn't know that and  i've learnt much, this isn't perfect solution for me becasue i'd have to change all my views, but thanks. :)